# Can the independence of cts functions always be checked thru differentiation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm wondering about the significance of the differentiation in this excerpt from a linear algebra book.  I guess because its a linear algebra book, they kind of glossed over why they are using the calculus part.  Seems like maybe the rate of change is important to show how they are independent or something?

[image]

Comment: It's not rate of change, it is that differentiation is linear $D(f+g) = Df +Dg$

Comment: So does their process for finding independence work for any linear operator, or is differentiation special in some way?

Comment: Ask yourself what aspects or what of its abilities would be relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the following theorem on your own:

> Two differentiable functions $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are linear independent if and only if the functions $Y_1(t)=(y_1(t),y_1'(t))$ and $Y_2(t)=(y_2(t),y_2'(t))$ are linear independent.

Consequently the system is given by

$$\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & e^{2t}\\
e^t & 2e^{2t}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
which has the unique solution $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: ... under the assumption that $y_1'$ and $y_2'$ even exist.

Comment: ...of course and this is true for $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following question is behind that Example.

---

If $(f_1,…,f_n)$ are linear independent in $V$, are $(Tf_1,…,Tf_n)$ linear independent in $V'$, with the linear mapping $T:V→V'$?

---

The mapping $T$ represents the differentiation $\frac{d}{dt}$,which is linear, as 
$$\frac{d}{dt}af+bg = a\frac{d}{dt}f+b\frac{d}{dt}g.$$

Now the statement is true, iff $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.    ($⇔ T$ injective)

Think about constant functions.

So if you exclude constant functions, which is true, since you look at exponential functions, everything works as intended.

Comment: Ah yeah I remember now, differentiation is a linear operator.  Thank you.